# Enqueuing Divi Child Theme But Styles Don't Override

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using the DIVI theme and am trying to enqueue the child theme to override the parent theme.  Here is the code in my functions.php:

```
// Queue parent style followed by child/customized style
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'parent-style' ) );
}
```

When I view source, everything is in the correct place.  However, code in the child theme is not overriding code in the parent style.  I've tried being more specific in my selectors, but no luck.

I've tried various versions of the enqueue code, I can see where my CSS is being called, but being overwritten by Divi's CSS.

While this isn't my favorite theme to work with, I'm stuck with it for this client.  If possible, I'd prefer to have my separate stylesheet work vs using the customizer or other workarounds.

Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**  The enqueue works as is.  I wasn't being specific enough in the child theme CSS to override the DIVI default CSS.